# Getting Items to Show Up In Shopping Cart?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am learning to write Android apps, and I am working on an e-commerce app. I keep getting a nullPointerException in the CartActivity when I go to the shopping cart. I am sure I have just missed something simple or have done something silly, but any input would be much appreciated! You do not need to tell me step by step but merely point me in the right direction. Please be kinds as I am new to Android Development.

Thank you!

I am including the relevant files and [LINK](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_KfGn8g2ijzoBgjuCEIMtLTVbeOENAEw/view?usp=sharing%22E-commerce%20App%22) to the whole project (just in case).

AboutActivity.java

```
package edu.phoenix.mbl402.week2apppp1943;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;

public class AboutActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_about);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

}
```

CartActivity.java

```
package edu.phoenix.mbl402.week2apppp1943;

import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Objects;
import static java.security.AccessController.getContext;

// TODO: WORK ON CART ACTIVITY
public class CartActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    CartActivity ca = new CartActivity();
    Product product = new Product();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

   String productId = getIntent().getStringExtra(MainActivity.PRODUCT_ID);
   product = DataProvider.productMap.get(productId);

    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameText);
    tv.setText(product.getName());

    NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    String price = formatter.format(product.getPrice());
    TextView priceText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.priceText);
    priceText.setText(price);

    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    Bitmap bitmap = ca.getBitmapFromAsset(product.getProductId());
    iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    String nCount = Integer.toString(product.getCount());
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.qty_in_cart)).setText(nCount);
}

/*    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.content_cart);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}*/
public Bitmap getBitmapFromAsset(String productId)
{
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    InputStream stream = null;

    try {
        stream = assetManager.open(productId + ".png");
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

DataProvider.java

```
package edu.phoenix.mbl402.week2apppp1943;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public final class DataProvider
{

public static List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>();
public static Map<String, Product> productMap = new HashMap<>();

static {

    addProduct("shirt101",
            "Umbrella T-Shirt",
            "Cute, red t-shirt, featuring a person chasing a flying away umbrella. Made with 100% cotton.",
            35);

    addProduct("jacket101",
            "Girls Pink Coat",
            "Super stylish, girls pink goose down coat. Stuffed with all natural goose down that contains a waterproof outer layer.",
            88);

    addProduct("outfit101",
            "Ladybug Girls Outfit",
            "Stylish girls ladybug outfit will have you looking fabulous. Made with 100% cotton and woven spandex fibers to move with you anywhere you go.",
            55);

    addProduct("shirt102",
            "Red Sushi T-Shirt",
            "Red t-shirt featuring chopsticks and a piece of sushi will have your child looking hip. Made with 100% cotton.",
            35);

    addProduct("shirt103",
            "Peppa Pig Onesie",
            "Peppa pig themed baby onesie, is perfect for easy clothing needs of a baby. Featuring sizes zero months to eighteen.",
            26);

    addProduct("shirt107",
            "Daddy Pig T-Shirt",
            "Daddy Pig themed t-shirt is perfect for Peppa Pig fans. Made with 100% cotton.",
            35);

    addProduct("shirt104",
            "Polo Shirt",
            "Our pre-shrunk organic cotton polo shirt is perfect for weekend activities, lounging around the house, and casual days at the park or school.",
            38);

    addProduct("shirt105",
            "Blue Hammerhead Shark T-Shirt",
            "Baby blue shark t-shirt is perfect for fans of sharks or just comfy t-shirts. Made with 100% cotton.",
            45);

    addProduct("jacket102",
            "Thermal Fleece Jacket",
            "Our thermal organic fleece jacket, is brushed on both sides for ultra softness and warmth. This medium-weight jacket is versatile all year around, and can be worn with layers for the winter season.",
            85);

    addProduct("shirt109",
            "Yellow Shark Graphic T-Shirt",
            "Bright yellow graphic t-shirt is an attention getter and great for school or out to play. Made with 100% cotton.",
            35);

    addProduct("shirt111",
            "Rainbow Unicorn T-Shirt",
            "Rainbow girls or boys unicorn t-shirt features a silly unicorn throwing up a rainbow.",
            28);

    addProduct("shirt108",
            "Yellow Mr. Strong T-Shirt",
            "Bright yellow t-shirt feature Mr. Strong from Mr. Happy and friends will bring back nostalgia. Made with 100% cotton.",
            75);

    addProduct("vest101",
            "Green Down Vest",
            "Green goose down vest is perfect for chilly mornings but not too hot that your little one suffers.",
            35);
}

private static void addProduct(String itemId, String name,
                               String description, double price) {
    Product item = new Product(itemId, name, description, price);
    productList.add(item);
    productMap.put(itemId, item);
}

public static List<String> getProductNames() {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Product product : productList) {
        list.add(product.getName());
    }
    return list;
}

public static List<Product> getFilteredList(String searchString) {

    List<Product> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Product product : productList) {
        if (product.getProductId().contains(searchString)) {
            filteredList.add(product);
        }
    }

    return filteredList;

}

}
```

DetailActivity.java

```
package edu.phoenix.mbl402.week2apppp1943;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.CryptoPrimitive;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
int count = 0;

//@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    String productId = getIntent().getStringExtra(MainActivity.PRODUCT_ID);
    final Product product = DataProvider.productMap.get(productId);

    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameText);
    tv.setText(product.getName());

    TextView descView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.descriptionText);
    descView.setText(product.getDescription());

    NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    String price = formatter.format(product.getPrice());
    TextView priceText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.priceText);
    priceText.setText(price);

    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromAsset(product.getProductId());
    iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            count++;
            String nCount = Integer.toString(count);
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.qty_in_cart)).setText(nCount);
//                Intent data = new Intent();
//                data.putExtra(MainActivity.RETURN_MESSAGE,
//                        product.getName() + " added to shopping cart");
//                setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
//                finish();
        }
    });
        //Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    FloatingActionButton fab_remove = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab_remove);
    fab_remove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            count--;
            String nCount = Integer.toString(count);
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.qty_in_cart)).setText(nCount);

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CartActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("Count", nCount);

            startActivity(intent);


        }
    });
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

private Bitmap getBitmapFromAsset(String productId)
{
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    InputStream stream = null;

    try {
        stream = assetManager.open(productId + ".png");
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package edu.phoenix.mbl402.week2apppp1943;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

private static final int MENU_ITEM_LOGOUT = 1001;
public static final String PRODUCT_ID = "PRODUCT_ID";

private static final int DETAIL_REQUEST = 1111;
public static final String RETURN_MESSAGE = "RETURN_MESSAGE";

private CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;

private static String webUrl = "http://www.google.com";
private static String email = "ppotter0003@gmail.com";

private List<Product> products = DataProvider.productList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.coordinator);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            // Send an email
            String[] addresses = {email};
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, addresses);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Information request");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Please send some information!");
            if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null)
            {
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });

    String[] items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.clothing);
//        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
//                new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
//                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
//                        android.R.id.text1, items);
    ProductListAdapter adapter = new ProductListAdapter(
            this, R.layout.list_item, products);
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);

            Product product = products.get(position);
            intent.putExtra(PRODUCT_ID, product.getProductId());

            startActivityForResult(intent, DETAIL_REQUEST);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    menu.add(0, MENU_ITEM_LOGOUT, 1001, R.string.logout);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{

    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch (id)
    {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout,
                    "You Selected settings", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_about:
            Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout,
                    "You Selected About", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, AboutActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        case R.id.action_web:
            //Go to the website
            Intent webIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(webUrl));
            if (webIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null)
            {
                startActivity(webIntent);
            }
            return true;
        case R.id.action_cart:
           Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout,
                   "Going To Shopping Cart", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
            intent = new Intent(this, CartActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
           return true;

        case MENU_ITEM_LOGOUT:
            Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout,
                    "You selected Logout", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (requestCode == DETAIL_REQUEST)
    {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            String message = data.getStringExtra(RETURN_MESSAGE);
            Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, message, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Go to cart", new View.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v)
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                    "Going to cart", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    }).show();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Product.java

```
package edu.phoenix.mbl402.week2apppp1943;

public class Product
{

private String productId;
private String name;
private String description;
private double price;
private int count;

public Product()
{

}

public String getProductId() {
    return productId;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description + "\n";
}

public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public int getCount() { return count; }

public Product(String productId, String name, String description, double price) {
    this.productId = productId;
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    this.price = price;
    this.count = count;
}

}
```

ProductListAdapter.java

```
package edu.phoenix.mbl402.week2apppp1943;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.List;

public class ProductListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Product>
{

private List<Product> products;

public ProductListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Product> objects)
{
    super(context, resource, objects);
    products = objects;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).
                inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    }

    Product product = products.get(position);

    TextView nameText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameText);
    nameText.setText(product.getName());

    NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    String price = formatter.format(product.getPrice());
    TextView priceText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.priceText);
    priceText.setText(price);

    ImageView iv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromAsset(product.getProductId());
    iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    return convertView;
}

public Bitmap getBitmapFromAsset(String productId)
{
    AssetManager assetManager = getContext().getAssets();
    InputStream stream = null;

    try {
        stream = assetManager.open(productId + ".png");
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

}
```

Here are the two xml files associated with CartActivity.java.
activity_cart.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="edu.phoenix.mbl402.week2apppp1943.CartActivity">



<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_cart" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

content_cart.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".CartActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_cart">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
    android:src="@drawable/jacket101"
    android:contentDescription="@string/description" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nameText"
    android:layout_width="256dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:text="@string/nameTextView"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:paddingStart="10dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/priceText"
    android:layout_width="145dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/nameText"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/priceTextView"
    android:textSize="14sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/qtyText"
    android:layout_width="56dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/priceText"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/priceText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/priceText"
    android:text="@string/qtyTextView"
    android:textSize="14sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/qty_in_cart"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/priceText"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/qty_in_cart"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:visibility="visible"
    tools:text="0" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/totalText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/priceText"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/priceText"
    android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
    android:text="@string/totalTextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/total_in_cart"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/qty_in_cart"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/total"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:visibility="visible"
    tools:text="0" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

I ultimately would like to be able to total the items prices in the cart, but I have not been able to even get anything to show up in the cart.

Comment: OMG that's to much code

Comment: attach your error log

Comment: Sorry for all the code. The issue is with CartActivity.java. Here is my error log only the pertinent one cause it too long:                    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String edu.phoenix.mbl402.week2apppp1943.Product.getName()' on a null object reference at edu.phoenix.mbl402.week2apppp1943.CartActivity.onCreate(CartActivity.java:42)

Answer (score 1):

Check the code where you are starting `CartActivity`

```
case R.id.action_cart:
       Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout,
               "Going To Shopping Cart", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show();
        intent = new Intent(this, CartActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
       return true;
```

You are not passsing `productId` to `CartActivity` and in your `CartActivity`, you are using `productId`

```
  String productId = getIntent().getStringExtra(MainActivity.PRODUCT_ID);
  product = DataProvider.productMap.get(productId);
```

So your `product` is null and it is crashing.